# Accessing a static variable and method in a module

Tags: ruby

I have a module defined as follows in `app/presenters/my_namespace/base_presenter.rb`:

```
module MyNamespace
  class BasePresenter
  end

  MY_SET = Set.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])

  def self.my_method
    true
  end
end
```

When I run `MyNamespace::MY_SET` or `MyNamespace::my_method` in the console, I get an uninitialized constant error, but I can do `MyNamespace::BasePresenter.new`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `MyNamespace::MY_SET` and `MyNamespace::my_method` should work. What error do you have?

Comment: Does `MyNamespace::MY_SET` work after you do `MyNamespace::BasePresenter.new`?

Comment: @AlexeyShein it does!! What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying this out in Rails development mode. In this mode all constants (classes, modules and constants) are loaded by demand.

When ruby meets undefined constant, it throws an error, which autoloader intercepts and tries to load the constant by converting its name to a path.

In your case, autoloader tries to find
`MyNamespace::MY_SET` in `app/presenters/my_namespace.rb` (which fails) and has no idea that you actually defined it in `app/presenters/my_namespace/base_presenter.rb`. But after you have loaded your `MyNamespace::BasePresenter` (which, btw, lies on the correct path), `MyNamespace`, `MyNamespace::MY_SET`, and `MyNamespace.my_method` got initialized and become available.

What you need to do is to

a) define `MyNamespace` correctly and move methods and constants to its definition:

> app/presenters/my_namespace.rb

```
module MyNamespace
  MY_SET = Set.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])

  def self.my_method
    true
  end
end
```

> app/presenters/my_namespace/base_presenter.rb

```
# note that I don't open module here, 
# but use a constant to enable autoloading of MyNamespace module
class MyNamespace::BasePresenter
end
```

or

b) just move all methods/constants to your `BasePresenter` class. Since it lies on a correct path, constant `MyNamespace::BasePresenter::MY_SET` will just work.

```
module MyNamespace
  class BasePresenter

    MY_SET = Set.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])

    def self.my_method
      true
    end
  end
end
```

## Bonus part

The difference between

```
module MyNamespace
  class BasePresenter
  end
end
```

and

```
class MyNamespace::BasePresenter
end
```

is when `MyNamespace` is undefined in first case it will be defined (`module MyNamespace` either opens existing module or *defines* new one), but in second case the mechanism described above will try to load `MyNamespace` somewhere, and if it fails - you'll get `uninitialized constant error MyNamespace`.

What it also means to you is if you define all your namespaced classes as a first case (inside `module MyNamespace`)

> app/presenters/my_namespace/base_presenter.rb

```
module MyNamespace
  class BasePresenter
  end
end
```

and also have `MyNamespace` in its proper place with some code inside

> app/presenters/my_namespace.rb

```
module MyNamespace
  MY_SET = Set.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])
end
```

And if your `MyNamespace::BasePresenter` will gets loaded first, it'll actually define `MyNamespace` and your `app/presenters/my_namespace.rb` will not be loaded (since autoloading loads only missing constants), and you'll have to `require` it yourself.

```
presenter = MyNamespace::BasePresenter.new
MyNamespace::MY_SET # boom, uninitialized constant error
```

The solution here is to define modules in 1 *proper* place (that autoloading knows how to find) and use `class MyNamespace::BasePresenter` format for defining namespaced classes in their proper locations.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! Could you elaborate on class MyNamespace::BasePresenter vs putting the class definition inside an open module?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that code, which suggests that the problem is a load (or reload) problem. Stop and restart your console, and/or `spring stop` if you have the default spring gem installed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not required the `set` gem. The class `Set` is defined in the `set` gem. It is part of the standard library, but not part of Ruby core. In that case, creation of `BasePresenter` succeeded because that was done prior to `MY_SET = Set.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])`, which raised the error. `MY_SET` and `my_method` were not defined because those definitions appear on or after the offending line.

You need to do:

```
require "set"
```

Comment: He uses Rails end it's required by default. Also he would get an error in the initialization if it was not initialized Set.